# Spring Cannot find the declaration of element Context

Tags: spring, context.xml

I have my database config file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<Context name="env">
<Context name="jdbc">
    <Resource name="testdb">
        <Property name="driver">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Property>
        <Property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db/Property>
        <Property name="username">test</Property>
        <Property name="password">test</Property>
        <Property name="read-only">false</Property>
        <Property name="connect-timeout">5</Property>  
        <Property name="max-connections">50</Property> 
        <Property name="max-idle-time">1800</Property>
        <Property name="max-life-time">7200</Property>
        <Property name="max-wait-time">5000</Property> 
        <Property name="max-idle">2</Property>
    </Resource>

</Context>
</Context>
```

When trying to deploy my web app I am getting below error

```
2014-06-20 02:44:19 ERROR ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 3 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 21; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Context'.


Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 21; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Context'.
```

I am using spring 4 and importing all spring 4 xsd.
xmlns
xmlns:mvc
xmlns:context
xsi:schemaLocation

Comment: You have confused server and spring configuration. context.xml is no part of the spring config and is missplaced in /WEB-INF.

Comment: Thanks Dirk for explanation.  Currently my context.xml is under resources/META-INF/ directory/ and when I am trying to refer that in my spring context file it says that datasource env/jdbc/ not found. Is that the correct place for this file.